# Stack level too deep error - what's wrong with this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I've a bit of repeated code in a controller I'm using, which I thought I'd drop into a method. However, doing so raises a 'stack level too deep' error. I understand this means there's an infinite loop in there somewhere, though I can't see it (I'm pretty new to this)!

Here's the controller code that works, though isn't DRY:

```
def cuisine
    if params[:cuisine].present?
      @recipes = Recipe.all.includes(:cuisines).where(cuisines: { name: params[:cuisine].humanize })
    end
    @message = "There are no recipes matching this cuisine. Please return to" if @recipes.empty?
    @user = current_user
    @count = @recipes.count
  end

  def category
    if params[:category].present?
      @recipes = Recipe.all.includes(:categories).where(categories: { name: params[:category].humanize })
    end
    @message = "There are no recipes matching this category. Please return to" if @recipes.empty?
    @user = current_user
    @count = @recipes.count
  end
```

I thought I could change the code to this, though that's where it's throwing up the error:

```
def category
  category_setter(category)
end

def cuisine
  category_setter(cuisine)
end

private

    def category_setter(c)
      @user = current_user
      @count = @recipes.count
      sym = c.to_sym
      syms = c.pluralize.to_sym
      if params[sym].present?
        @recipes = Recipe.all.includes(syms).where(syms: { name: params[sym].to_s.humanize })
      end
      @message = "There are no recipes matching this #{sym}. Please return to" if @recipes.empty?
    end
```

It's displayed as such in the view:

```
<div>
      <% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
        <% if ingredient_matcher(@user, recipe)  %>
          </br><strong><%= recipe.name %></strong>
              <ul>
                <% recipe.ingredients.each do |ing| %>
                  <li><%= ing.name.humanize %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
              <p><%= recipe.method %></p>
        <% else %>
          <% @count -= 1  %>
        <% end %> 
      <% end %>
</div>
```

Using this helper method:

```
def ingredient_matcher(one, two)
    (one.fridge.ingredients.pluck(:id) & two.ingredients.pluck(:id)) == two.ingredients.pluck(:id)
  end
```

Hope that's all the code needed for someone to be able to shed some light on to this - I'm thinking it'll be something pretty straightforward I'm missing!

Thanks in advance, Steve.

Comment: Could you post your error stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are causing infinite recursion here:

```
def category
  category_setter(category)
end
```

and here:

```
def cuisine
  category_setter(cuisine)
end
```

Instead of passing the method name, call your setter method passing it a String:

```
category_setter('category')
```

And

```
category_setter('cuisine')
```

Comment: That did it - thanks @dgilperez, much appreciated! In case anyone else visits this and wants to use similar code, the line `@recipes = Recipe.all.includes(syms).where(syms: { name: params[sym].to_s.humanize })` needed to be changed to `@recipes = Recipe.all.includes(syms).where(syms => { name: params[sym].to_s.humanize })` to get it working properly.